# Java Regex Word Extract exclude with special char

Tags: java, regex

below are the String values

```
"method" <in> abs
("method") <in> abs
method <in> abs
```

i want to extract only the Word `method`, i tries with below regex

`"(^[^\\<]*)"` its included the special char also

O/p for the above regex

```
"method"
("method")
method
```

my expected output

```
method
method
method
```

Comment: Is `method` always a sequence of non-whitespace characters, or can there be any spaces?

Comment: yes it may have whitespace or multiple words "method and apparatus" <in> abs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^\\W*(\\w+)
```

You can use this and grab the `group 1` or `capture 1`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sS2dM8/20

Comment: thanks vks let me know what will be if more than one word i.e "method and apparatus" <in> abs

Answer (score 1):

A couple of words on your `"(^[^<]*)"` regex: it does not match because it has beginning of string anchor `^` after `"`, which is never the case. However, even if you remove it `"([^<]*)"`, it will not match the last case where `"` and `(` are missing. You need to make them optional. And note the brackets must escaped, and the order of quotes and brackets is different than in your input.

So, your regex could be fixed as

```
^\(?"?(\b[^<]*)\b"?\)?(?=\s+<)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/cB9kE8/1)

However, I'd suggest using a replaceAll approach:

```
String rx = "(?s)\\(?\"?(.*?)\"?\\)?\\s+<.*";
System.out.println("\"My method\" <in> abs".replaceAll(rx, "$1"));
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/Gj4Vwp)

If the strings start with `("My method`, you can also add `^` to the beginning of the pattern: `String rx = "(?s)^\\(?\"?(.*?)\"?\\)?\\s+<.*";`.

The regex `(?s)^\\(?\"?(.*?)\"?\\)?\\s+<.*` matches:

- `(?s)` makes `.` match a newline symbol (may not be necessary)
- `^` - matches the beginning of a string
- `\\(?` - matches an optional `(`
- `\"?`  - matches an optional `"`
- `(.*?)` - matches and captures into Group 1 any characters as few as possible
- `\"?`   - matches an optional `"`
- `\\)?`  - matches an optional `)`
- `\\s+` - matches 1 or more whitespace
- `<` - matches a `<`
- `.*` - matches 0 or more characters to the end of string.

With `$1`, we restore the group 1 text in the resulting string.

Comment: @Prabu: Please have a look at my solution, it support multiple words.

Comment: Vks answer will fail on `("My-method") <in> abs`. You also need to use `Matcher` and `Pattern` explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

In fact it is not too complicated.
Here is my answer:

```
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z]+)");
        String[] myStrs = {
                "\"method\"",
                "(\"method\")",
                "method"
                };

        for(String s:myStrs) {
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
            if(matcher.find()) {
                System.out.println( matcher.group(0) );
            }
        }
```

The output is:

```
method
method
method
```

You just need to use:

```
[a-zA-Z]+
```